# Can power theft on a large scale be stopped

Tags: power-engineering, power-consumption

Reading [this](http://news.yahoo.com/pakistan-utility-company-fights-power-chaotic-port-megacity-233951436.html) article, I started wondering if there is any way to stop people stealing electricity from a power grid. Let me clarify, the only techniques I have seen (and can think of) is either to

1. rely on an honor system where you trust people not to steal and pay for all the power they consume
2. or have visual inspections where a power company just sends its people out they look for illegal hookups and then either just disconnecting them and/or legal action against the thieves.

For the second case, as the article says, power company employees cut the hookups and then the hookups are back up again in five minutes and legal action of any kind is useless and hopeless thanks to massive corruption at all levels.

My question here is, is there any method or technique based on principles of electromagnetism/electrical engineering/grid designing that can prevent/minimize such theft or even detect such theft like where it is happening or who is doing it? Is there anyway to localize it and then cut only the thieves instead of an entire neighborhood including innocents who are not stealing at all? Can a power grid be designed (from scratch if needed) to help with this? Can at least the theft be made so difficult or expensive that it won't be worthwhile for people to steal it?

I understand that security of any kind is a difficult problem and no matter what the system, there is always a way to break it. But in this police/legal action is absolutely useless so how can power distribution be made *secure enough* that it is beyond the scope/ability/affordability of an average citizen to just brazenly and easily steal all the power they want. Thank you.

Comment: Depends. Do the physics of a bullet being fired from a gun count?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nope, physics meaning physics of electromagnetism.

Comment: A downvote already? Without any explanation? How come?

Comment: In my opinion, a technological solution is useless in a country where kidnapping, murder, and corruption are the norm.  Any security system can be breached by corrupt or extorted operators.  As many security experts frequently say, the weakest link is the human.  I cannot envision a security system that will work for this scenario, but even if there was one it would fail because the people themselves will fail.  BTW: I didn't downvote.

Comment: Even theoretically, is any such system possible? Are any of the grids in the developed world *secure* or do they all rely on the honor system and legal action?

Comment: @FixedPoint  In the United States, power theft does happen-- particularly with Marijuana grow houses, where a "legal power bill" would be many thousands of dollars a month and would attract lots of attention.  As I said before, I cannot envision any security system that would work in any practical sense.  I also do not know of any system other than "monitor the power and find leaks".

Comment: What about the impedance of the line? Would it be possible to determine where a device was connected without knowledge of the characteristics of the device? How about if voltage/current sensors were finely distributed throughout the line?

Comment: No system that allows physical access is secure. All systems that transmit power must allow physical access. Remote detection is possible, but individual disconnection is not, because physical access allows bypassing disconnection.

Comment: @david So how is remote detection possible? Can you please elaborate on that? In an answer perhaps? As for physical access, what about an underground grid to restrict physical access? I guess theoretically an underground grid would work but not practical, right? You do need legitimate access like repair work, etc.

Comment: Suppose that all legitimate meters are smart and they can convey minute-by-minute usage back to the base (in real time or not).  If the amount of power (I'm using this term loosely) going into the branch is larger than the total of the meters, than there is a leak.

Comment: In many jurisdictions illegally connecting to a power grid is a criminal offense and I'm pretty sure that the police would not be *useless* there.

Comment: @sharptooth It is illegal in Pakistan as well but the police IS useless. The legality/illegality doesn't matter. The problem is *enforcement*. If the law enforcers are corrupt then it doesn't matter if "illegally connecting to a power grid is a criminal offense". Anyway, this has nothing to do with the question. For the question we assume that the legal route is completely useless so my question is, is there any technological/scientific/engineering solution?

Comment: Well, this is why I posted this as a comment.

Comment: Illegal hook-ups and meter tampering are also a problem in my country. I've had opportunity to talk to some of the people working on the projects to solve the issue and it seems that the main problem are the people, just as it was previously mentioned. Even without smart meters, it's possible to somewhat localize leakage points. Adding more meters along the distribution path and comparing their readings to expected loses and readings of user meters can show meter tampering and illegal connections to the grid.

Comment: After the locations of the power-thieves are identified, the most difficult problem comes: Actually disconnecting them from the grid and having the legal system persecute them. Government usually wants to hide the issue in order not to antagonize future voters, police gives its best not to cooperate, allowing direct conflict between thieves and technicians who are supposed to disconnect them, courts often extremely low sentences (for example just a few hundred Euros fine for damage in the thousands range). So even when technology is available, it can't fix a rotten system.

Comment: Reduce the size of the power distribution company to that of a community small enough that the thief is known to the community.

This could be done by metering the total power delivered to each small community, as well as each customer in it. If the total power delivered is higher than the total of each customer's, there is a thief in the community. Let them (the community) know, raise their bill, and let them ferret out the culprit.

Comment: If the power grid is subsidized in any way, there is already robbing anyway: you can pay peanuts for electricity and use more than others, and someone else is paying for you.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: The problem with adding up all the power seen by a collection of smart meters is that it assumes all the meters are accurate and there are no power losses in transmission. In reality, even revenue meters are only accurate to approx 1% and the electrical losses in transformers, cables and overhead lines are significant - so the sums never balance perfectly. Only very large electricity thieves would be noticeable above the uncertainty in the measurements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "honour system" or visual inspections are not the only two options.

Detecting tapping-off points is possible using a *[time domain reflectometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer)* (TDR). This is a measurement instrument that uses transmission line physics to determine locations and types of "impedance discontinuities" (such as illegal taps) on a transmission line.

#### Operating principle

TDRs work by sending a "ping" of energy into a transmission line and watching the "echoes" that come back. The transmission line can be an optical transmission line (i.e. an optical fibre) or, in our case, an electrical transmission line (a overhead power line or underground power cable.)

This works because signals will [partially or fully reflect off any discontinuity in a transmission line.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines) A "discontinuity" in this case could be the end of the line (open circuit, short circuit, or terminated in a load), any tapping-off point, or any change in impedance.

The TDR works by analysing the length of time between sending out the signal and receiving it back, so it can tell you the physical distance between the instrument and the source of the echo. [This can be done to a precision of centimeters.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer#Usage)

#### Normal uses of TDRs

The main use of TDRs is to detect faults on [cables](http://megger.com/au/Products/ProductDetails.php?ID=1762&Description=tdr) or optical fibres.

Say that electric waves propagate at 0.66c (~200,000 km/sec) you have a 100 kilometre long wire, open circuit at the far end. If you send a pulse down one end of the wire, you would expect the echoes to bounce off the end of the wire and return in 1 millisecond (200km round trip distance.)

If you send a pulse down this 100km wire and the reflection comes back in 0.4 milliseconds, this tells you that there is a discontinuity 40% of the way down the wire (i.e. around the 40km mark.) Further analysis of the magnitude and shape of the echo can tell you what kind of discontinuity is present at that location, i.e. a complete break, a kink, corrosion, **tapping-off point**, splice, etc.

This is widely used in the electrical industry to locate faults on long cables. It's also used for the same purpose in telecommunications, to diagnose faults and (oddly enough) to [locate surveillance wire taps.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer#Usage)

#### Detecting illegal power line tap-offs

A power transmission line obeys the same physical principles as a telecommunications cable or an optical fibre, so in theory, TDR can be used to locate illegal tap-offs from a power line.

This idea isn't new or novel - there is at least [one mob](http://hjarnett.com/products/revenue-protection/) selling commercial products that detect illegal power line taps using this method. I note the Megger CFL510G instrument is a general purpose instrument intended for fault-finding on telecommunications equipment so it probably requires disconnection of the mains power before use.

To answer your original question, I would guess that using TDR to detect power theft on a large scale is technically possible but too expensive.

- The distribution authority would have to send men around to every neighbourhood to perform periodic TDR testing. You have to pay their wages and equipment.
- Depending on the particular instrument, using it might involve disconnecting the consumer's power. This would be both unpopular and expensive (the distribution company gets paid $$$ based on how many kilowatts you consume, and disconnected customers don't consume any kilowatts!)
- The vast majority of people probably aren't stealing power, so you have to balance the cost of finding the power thieves vs. the cost of the electricity they are stealing.

Answer (score 2):

One more or less practical way would be to supply high voltage (say 6 kilovolts) as close to the consumer as possible and convert it to mains voltage there.

For example [here goes a *small* pole-mounter transformer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPolemount-singlephase-closeup.jpg) that is typical in North America and is rated at 200 Amps (presumably at 110 volts and that gets 22 kilowatts which is fine for 2-10 households). It is installed right in front of a house it serves, then wires run to the house or two or three nearby houses. Smaller transformers are possible. The article you linked to also showed a pole-mounted transformer but that one is much larger and so serves more consumers.

This would assume that laymen would not mess with high voltage and also the connections to such transformers are easily visible. Now if the grid operator finds abuse he can disconnect only one or several consumers, not a neighborhood.

One bonus is that this reduces losses - since only the last hundred meters is at mains voltage the efficiency is increased. The downside is that low power transformers are more expensive per watt of power and you have more high voltage wires around the houses and this might reduce safety in case of accidents.

Comment: That would help with new housing estates but it could be a problem to upgrade x squillions of miles of local overhead cable currently sitting on 240V insulators. You'd still have to monitor n = 1 billion/people-per-household/households-per-pole transformers pretty often to remove hooks on the low(er)-voltage side and possibly still have to bribe the police/politicians/gangs/militia to enforce the law and/or to allow disconnections.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Sure, but when you have 220 volts grid for the whole neighborhood theft is much easier.

Comment: `This would assume that laymen would not mess with high voltage ` In my country at least, this assumption has been proven incorrect. We regularly have deaths of people trying to steal copper from automated high-voltage transformer yards  and railway power installations.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: That's a bit different - they only need to cut the wire and carry it with them, not provide a good electrical connection.

Comment: The tin foil hat crowd would have a field day with this.

Comment: This proposal would do more harm than good. 1) People would just steal from each other instead of from the shared power cables, 2) inefficiency loss of economy of scale, 3) massive resource loss from overhaul of infrastructure, and 4) increased risk of death from pervasive high voltage lines.

Comment: Using tiny transformers is problematic because each household's energy demand is "peaky". E.g. most of the time, houses draw only a few hundred watts of power, but if you turn on a a dishwasher (2 kW), a microwave (2 kW), a air conditioner (8 kW)... it can stack up quickly. So the peak load can be 20 kW per house. The only reason why a 1,000 house neighbourhood doesn't need a 20 MW transformer is because (statistically) it's unlikely that all these loads will be running full bore all the time. This statistical assumption is only true if the number of houses on each transformer is large.